# I-94 exit record?

Tags: usa, i-94

Does the exit get recorded in your I-94 history? I don't see it on my most recent I-94 on the online portal, I just see Date of entry, Admitted until date but nothing about departure date.

Comment: How did you exit the US? By air, sea or land?

Comment: A couple of thoughts.  1 - it can sometimes take a few days to show up on the portal.  2 - Are you looking at the right place?  Your I-94 record shows the I-94, not the entry.  There is a Travel History section on the portal which shows your entry and exit records separate to the I-94

Comment: And if you exited by land there is possibly no exit record